# What's the deal if I upload MY copyrighted image?

Tags: discussion, copyright

This question on Meta Stack Exchange may be of interest for other users here: [Is my copyrighted artwork protected if I upload it to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309025/is-my-copyrighted-artwork-protected-if-i-upload-it-to-a-post)

> Moderator’s notice: This is just an announcement. Please do not discuss the actual question here.

Comment: Closing this question so it serves its purpose letting our members see the notice. Once resolved soon SE we will copy it over here.

Comment: @Ryan: Unclosing this, so it may appear in the sidebar (at least it hasn’t done for me until now).

Comment: Could the community do a favor to at least paraphrase the question and answer on here so that they don't need to go to MSE to understand the whole discussion? While this is meta, I assume Q&A on SE still needs to be self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist of the Meta question and answers are....

**Anything** you upload here gets attributed a [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) Creative Commons license. This is *especially* true if you use the inline imgur image uploader when answering/posting.

The only possible way to prevent this attribution may be:

- Link to images hosted elsewhere rather than posting images inline
- Quote images (hosted elsewhere, not on imgur - i.e. hotlink) and indicate that the image is *not* part of the CC attribution.

In short, there appears to be *no solid method* to prevent the CC attribution when you add an image to a post/answer. So, if you are concerned about reuse, merely **don't** post the image you are concerned about, at least not here. Link back to it (via a text link not an image link) on some other server.

Comment: Note that linking an image externally should be reserved for exceptional cases. External images are subject to link rot and for most images posted here, there is no reason why the authors would want to avoid a CC license.

Comment: I agree @Wrzlprmft in *most* instances this shouldn't be a concern. I mean, who is seeking to protect screenshots?? Which you can't anyway due to UI copyrights :)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft and Scott - actually there is very valid reason which is what Scott just said. The UI is copyrighted. You, not holding that copyright, have no authority to release it to the CC license. If we're going to get all technical.

Comment: @Ryan: If you have no authority to publish it on SE Imgur, you usually also have no authority to host it anywhere else (unless you are subject to some highly specific contract).